# Resources for multisignature transactions?

Tags: transactions, api, multi-signature, safety

I am interested in using multisignature transactions to secure my company's coins and I'm wondering what tools are available right now for use with multisignature transactions? I'm especially interested in solutions that work on keys distributed between multiple wallets (no single wallet holds all the keys) and are not currency specific (would work just as well for Bitcoin as for Litecoin or other coins).

I know that the standard bitcoind API is lacking in multisignature support due to [this bug](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3218).

Comment: bitrated.com has a nice implementation of them.

Comment: wow, that's a really bad multisig implementation.  just sayin

Answer (score 1):

blocktrail has a 2of3 HD Multisig Wallet API, it's setup like: 
 - the 1st key being your primary key to use
 - the 2nd key being a backup key you store offline and 
 - the 3rd key being a cosign key owned by blocktrail

it only supports bitcoin and bitcoin testnet atm though ...

https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs#payments_overview

Answer (score 0):

I know [darkwallet.is](http://darkwallet.is) supports multisignature transactions and multi-sig wallets.  I haven't used them.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: Just guessing here, but it might be due to the typo "darwallet.io", which should probably be [darkwallet.io](http://darkwallet.io). Also, link-only answers are considered very low quality.

Comment: darkwallet.io doesn't even resolve for me, perhaps the link was supposed to be https://darkwallet.is?

Answer (score 0):

The current multisig solutions are all quite awkward - they don't handle transmitting partially signed transactions too well. But you might want to read up on Armory: http://www.coindesk.com/armorys-lockbox-multisig-storage-escrow/

You could use [Orisi oracles](http://orisi.org) for that. Every person "holding" a key would be running an oracle node, and funds would be stored and withdrawn by sending requests from the client. Orisi is now in Alpha, and it would probably a month of programming for one programmer to do it this way, but it's doable and you could probably recruit some help on [the forum](http://orisi.net)